# NodeJS passport facebook error after a few requests

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, passport-facebook, passport.js

So I have this problem on my site that after I logged in as a facebook user and after I clicked few links, NGINX error page will come out. But when I test it on another browser that does not logged in as a facebook user, it won't give an error.

By the way I used 'express-mysql-session' as my session store.

Comment: Impossible to help without any error messages or logs.

Comment: Yeah :( It has no error log also.